# Проверка диапазона и последовательности Regex

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как я могу проверить диапазон на правильность?

[от, до]

Правильно:

[23, 45]

[ 23,34]

[     23,      45]     (в начале и конце могут быть пробелы, а также перед [ и за ])

Неправильно:

[12 32]

32, 45]

[45, 93

А также как проверить последовательность:

(234, 453, 875, 345)

В последовательности может быть любой количество чисел, а также пробелы в любом месте, кроме чисел

Comment: Только пробелы или табы тоже? Числа N-значные или только двухзначные? Пробелы перед запятой могут быть?

Comment: Второй вопрос задавайте отдельно, он не связан с первым никак

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/2xg7Qv/3 - вот под оба случая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот (любой whitespace, N-значные числа, пробелов перед запятой не может быть):

```
^\s*\[\s*\d+,\s*\d+\s*\]\s*$
```

Тест https://regexr.com/59nn4

> **[23, 45]**
>
> **[ 23,34]**
>
> **[ 23, 45]**
>
> [12 32]
>
> 32, 45]
>
> [45, 93